# Advantage of using Low Grade Fuel compared to Wood

Tags: rust

Is there an advantage to using [*Low grade fuel*](http://rust.wikia.com/wiki/Low_grade_fuel) compared to [*Wood*](http://rust.wikia.com/wiki/Wood) in Rust? Does it burn longer/shorter, faster/slower etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LGF converts your minerals in roughly a third of the time it takes for wood to convert your minerals.](http://www.reddit.com/r/playrust/comments/1ydghg/what_is_the_more_economical_fuel_low_grade_fuel/)

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Is there a wiki or testing proof of this or is this just personal experience?